# Is it possible to change size or position of a textbox via embedded code or an expression in a RDLC report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc

Why would I want to do this?

Well, the think is I don't want to resize or to set a new position for an element, I have [these components](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApW59jc1oGeBoutNRIqBdT0sMSLdsw) in my footer.

This is one of [the output](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApW59jc1oGeBoutOT5-msHkIz5ZP4A) I "build" based on some parameters.

As you can see I hide some elements, I'm using the following properties:

- CanShrink
- Allow decrease height
- Hidden

The problem is the space between my not-hidden elements, it is almost like the hidden ones were there. That's why I was thinking in move them, maybe change their size in order to get something like [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApW59jc1oGeBoutPxMZ94PTFV8sACA):

Every approach, suggestion and advice will be welcome.

Thank you.

PS: Sorry about the images, not enough reputation to post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this without a table. Considering that I need to do this inside the report's footer I had to change my approach and started to use a (static) row footer in my body's table. Hiding a row from my table does not show any blank space of my dynamic footers (even though I use rectangles on them).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the elements you hid in your example were all inside a rectangle. The size of the rectangle doesn't change when you hide them. One alternative would be to place those elements in a table instead. Then you can hide the entire column and the table height will shrink. Obviously, the expression to hide the column may be slightly more complex, but this should work for you. Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi, yes, it is inside a rectangle. I'd prefer to use a table as you comment but these elements are inside the footer section and unfortunately headers and footers aren't able to content tables. I'll explore your option by putting these elements inside my body's main table (fixed row). I hope this works.

Thank you.